Feasible to implement AI interacting with webpages?
I'm in the process of doing a personal project and I think it might be a good idea to create an app that can help people retrieve information from the Web, based on their needs. However, after several trials, I'm in doubt whether the technology currently available is sufficient for such a purpose.
I experimented with https://www.lavague.ai/ and tweaked some parameters, but it does not even seem to be able to set the filters on Craigslist correctly.
This result seems counter-intuitive, because nowadays human-like robots can even manipulate complex objects. There is no reason why we are unable to create some robot interacting with web-pages.
Am I underestimating the difficulty of doing this? Any suggestions or advice is welcome.
Best regards,


Feasible to implement AI interacting with webpages?

Yes, e.g. see the following model and benchmark: Mind2Web: Towards a Generalist Agent for the Web. Xiang Deng, Yu Gu, Boyuan Zheng, Shijie Chen, Samuel Stevens, Boshi Wang, Huan Sun, Yu Su. NeurIPS'23 Spotlight. (code+data, site).
Another benchmark requiring interacting with webpages: GAIA

